Want to record audio of background(system) audio & user's input through microphone
I want to code in simple HTML, JS/Jquery for recording an audio of user's microphone and background audio(instrumental song). So how to do ?
I have tried like this way:
When I click on Start recording then background(system) audio becomes muted & when I stop recording then I am not able to record anything.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Access DOM elements
    const backgroundAudio = document.getElementById('background-audio');
    const startRecordingButton = document.getElementById('start-recording');
    const stopRecordingButton = document.getElementById('stop-recording');
    const recordedAudio = document.getElementById('recorded-audio');

    // Setup Web Audio API context
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    let mediaRecorder;
    let recordedChunks = [];

    startRecordingButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            // Request access to the microphone
            const micStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

            // Create a MediaElementAudioSourceNode for the background audio
            const backgroundAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(backgroundAudio);

            // Create a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode for the microphone stream
            const micSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);

            // Create a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode to capture the combined audio
            const destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

            // Connect the audio nodes
            backgroundAudioSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
            backgroundAudioSource.connect(destination);
            micSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
            micSource.connect(destination);

            // Initialize MediaRecorder with the destination stream
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(destination.stream);

            // Handle dataavailable event
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {
                    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
                }
            };

            // Handle stop event
            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                // Create a blob from the recorded chunks
                const recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
                recordedChunks = []; // Reset the recorded chunks

                // Create a URL for the recorded audio and set it as the source for the audio element
                const recordedAudioURL = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
                recordedAudio.src = recordedAudioURL;
                recordedAudio.controls = true;
            };

            // Start recording
            mediaRecorder.start();

            // Play the background audio
            backgroundAudio.play();

            // Update the UI
            startRecordingButton.disabled = true;
            stopRecordingButton.disabled = false;

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
            alert('Could not access the microphone. Please check your permissions.');
        }
    });

    stopRecordingButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
            // Stop the media recorder
            mediaRecorder.stop();

            // Pause the background audio
            backgroundAudio.pause();

            // Update the UI
            startRecordingButton.disabled = false;
            stopRecordingButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
            console.warn('MediaRecorder is not recording.');
        }
    });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sing Along App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sing Along with Background Music</h1>
    <audio id="background-audio" controls>
        <source src="instrumental.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div>
        <button id="start-recording">Start Recording</button>
        <button id="stop-recording" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
    </div>
    <h2>Recorded Audio</h2>
    <audio id="recorded-audio" controls></audio>

    <script src="recording.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



